Spring security without spring and spring boot
Is it possible to use spring security without spring and spring boot. I am working on a old project which doesn't use spring or spring boot, upgrading to spring or spring boot is not possible as of now due to other older library dependencies. Any documentation or guide on how to use spring security without spring or spring boot or what are the steps I should follow?
I went through the documentation of spring security and tried I am able to understand how it works with springboot. But I am not understanding how I will achieve the same thing without spring and spring boot.

You can achieve a similar kind of spring security logic with the help of Java Filters and implementing the other authentication, authorization mechanism . It is  not as simple but you can achieve it.

using the java filters to perform authentication without spring security?. Is that mean spring security cannot be used without a spring or spring boot? I see spring security also does use filters so I thought it is possible.

Yes spring security requires spring auto configuration mechanism without it won’t work.

If you don't want to use spring security then maybe look at 3rd party integrations. Maybe take a look at Keycloak.
